# Restrict Google Analytics to persist local data for too long

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I have read a lot about setting a dispatch interval, which will send Google Analytics (GA) data periodically and make future retries if there is no network connection etc.

GA documentation regarding dispatching: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/dispatch

Think of the issue as of, for instance, using an iPad aboard a submarine and now and then it surfaces and the iPad might be able to send large chunks of analytics data (it might get problematic being out at sea looking for wifi or 3G etc.).

So, it's not sure that the user will ever have a network connection and that there might be a long period of time until the next network access (+ app being run during that specific access as well). This means that GA will persist the data/hits in the local storage for a possibly very long time. I have tried to find any documentation regarding for how long hits/data will be stored and if there are any settings to restrict the offline persistence, either specified in maximum time or maybe in max memory being used for this service.

I know that you can choose to manually handle when the tracking is made, but this should not be a very unusual scenario for the "auto mode" to handle, right?

If you have any insights or recommendations, please feel free. Thanks!